# I have downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 amd64.iso but ended up with 32bit OS

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, downloads, 32-bit

I did ask this question before, I know, but as a newbee couldn't find my question again.

Anyway, I have downloaded (twice) what I thought was the 64 bit version of 13.04 but when I check 'About this computer' it tells me that I have the 32 bit version.

Comment: Did your Computer With 64 Bit capable Hardware ?

Comment: Hi - Yes it did. It has an AMD 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link for the 64 bit version - just to avoid any confusion.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=latest

If you download and install this, but still end up with a 32 bit o/s .. then I think its time we called Mulder and Scully out :)

Good Luck